# "Do you want to go mummy there?"

Tags: grammaticality

Does this sentence make sense?

> Do you want to go mummy there?

When you and your kid are in room A, and his mummy is in room B, can we say "Do you want to go mummy there?" to your kid to ask him whether he wants to go to his mother's room?

Preposition question: do I need to add "to" after go?

Comment: Done Edited....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That sentence casts *mummy* as the direct object of *go*; but *go* is intransitive, it does not take a direct object. You must express the target as a preposition phrase:

> Do you want to go **to** mummy there?

Comment: @Chipperyman: I assure you no native English speaker would say "go mummy" when they mean "go to mummy".

Comment: Personally I'd suggest "Do you want to go to mummy?" or "Do you want to go to mummy's room?"  Ending the sentence with "there" sounds a bit awkward.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I assure you not even any non-native would do that! :)

Comment: "Go is intransitive" - Some would go mad when reading that :P

Answer (score 3):

[StoneyB's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24651/4468) deals with the missing "to". In addition, the "there" at the end of the sentence is redundant and unnatural. You can, for example, go to a restaurant in London or Paris or New York because there are restaurants in all of those places. But mummy is only in one place and you can only go to mummy in that place: it doesn't make sense to add a word to describe where you're going.

Comment: Belatedly - It may be relevant if the child doesn't know where mummy is and the there is accompanied by a point or something. I suspect more punctuation may be needed in that case though or something. The words in that order could be used in some situations though is the point I'm trying to make.